# How to install a wifi n router as "invisible"?

Tags: networking, network-protocols

All right I admit that it seems like a weird question, and keep in mind (in case you didn't understand it already by the question) I am really not a networking guy, but let me explain:

I work in an office with one (that's right) wall mounted female Ethernet port per desktop PC (about 4 total...all on different sides of the room). This port not only provides Internet access but it also provides access for all desktop  PCs to the network for the rest of the building (Alas, I have no direct access to this network, nor I know anything about it).

As I am an external consultant I really don't need/care about the network resources but I do need Internet access for various tasks. I work with a laptop and there is WiFi provided by the company, but as it turns out the desk where I have to sit at is barely in range of this company provided Access Point. Signal is lost often, and I waste hours upon hours trying to get logged back on when I get dropped out. However, my desk is extremely close to one of these wall mounted ports, on which the office's boss computer is plugged into.

So I thought, "Hey, I'll just buy and hoop-up a simple little router to the wall plug and connect both my computer and the boss' computer to the router using good ol' fashioned Ethernet cables (both in a straight-through configuration). Problem solved!"

And it worked like a charm. Or so I thought.

See, the problem is that the boss computer suddenly disappeared from the network (while keeping full Internet functionality, as I did) and as my famously good luck would have it, that computer has some important resources that are needed from the rest of the team/building. Ironically, I was the only one that could see the boss computer on my network because we were connected through the router.

As the local tech support guy explained it, the boss PC could not be found on the network because it had a different IP address which wasn't recognized (these were the actual words he used). Alas, he didn't notice my little router so I unplugged it and fixed the problem for him without him even noticing it.

Maybe the simple diagram below will illustrate better the situation at hand:

```
  Original Configuration:


   ____  Wall mounted Female RJ-45 Plug
  | [] |
  ''''''                      [MyLaptop(with crappy WiFi)]
    ||                 
    ^^^^^^^^^[BossPC]

  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Modified Configuration using TP-Link TL-WR740N N Wireless Router:


   ____  Wall mounted Female RJ-45 Plug
  | [] |
  ''''''                ^^^^^^^^^[MyLaptop]
    ||                  ||
    ||                  ||---------------------------------
    ||                 (Tp-Link TL-WR740N N Wireless Router)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''^^^^^^^^^^^[BossPC]
```

Keep in mind that for now I disabled WiFi completely while configuring the router since I don't need it.

My question is the following:

Is there a way, or a specific set of configuration settings I must use to make it so that I can use this router hard wired as shown above, but that would look "transparent" to the rest of the network? (By "transparent" I mean in a way that my Boss PC can still be viewed by everybody just like it did in the Original Configuration)

Comment: You need a network switch. The company probably has an extra somewhere.

Comment: It sounds like they are using a common network idiom of 192.168.1.x.. Just change your Wireless Router's IP address and see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to make it work as per your description; however, not all of the approaches would work due to the company's security infrastructure.  Let's try the simple way first.

1) Disable DHCP on the TP-Link
2) Enable WIFI with your preference settings
3) Plug the wall jack to the TP-Link LAN port (not WAN)
4) Plug Boss's computer to another LAN port
5) Connect your computer to the WIFI with DHCP client enable

Note: In order for you to manage the TP-Link again, you would need to set your computer with static IP address, which must be the same range as the TP-Link IP.  Example, if you TP-Link IP is 192.168.1.1 with subnet 255.255.255.0.  Then you should set your IP to 192.168.1.10 with subnet 255.255.255.0.

Kindly comment on the post if this does not solve your issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello there, i just wanted to say that your instructions were spot-on. I tried it one time at work and I failed miserably (told you I wasn't a network guy). I tried it again now at home and seems to be working fine, I will run a work test in the morning...I was wondering, if it isn't too much trouble, could you explain exactly what you had me do? It's the first time I find myself hooking up the Internet to a LAN port and have it working perfectly....=) I will let you know tomorrow how it goes regardless...thanks

Comment: UPDATE-it works GREAT!!! You really helped me out. THANK YOU